# Why does my while loop repeat the same statement when it should be random?

Tags: java, string, while-loop

```
     List<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
 n.add("Allen");
 n.add("beer");
 n.add("Johnson");
 n.add("bar");
 n.add("girl");
   List<String> v = new ArrayList<String>();
 v.add("shot");
 v.add("drank");
 v.add("ate");
 v.add("hit");
 v.add("tossed");
     int noun = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
     int verb = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
     int noun2 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
     int verb2 = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
     int noun3 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
     String a = new String(n.get(noun) + " " + v.get(verb) + " " + n.get(noun2) + " " +  "and" + " " + v.get(verb2) + " " + n.get(noun3));

  int x = 0;
  while (x < 5) {
       System.out.println(a);
   x++;
 }
```

It then proceeds to repeat only one statement such as:

Johnson tossed bar and hit bar

Johnson tossed bar and hit bar

Johnson tossed bar and hit bar

Johnson tossed bar and hit bar

Johnson tossed bar and hit bar

how do I make it random in which it's different everytime.

Comment: What do you want to randomize exactly?

Comment: if the randomization happens outside the loop the values will never change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only running your assignment of the string once. So it will always be the same. Put your assignment:

```
String a = new String(n.get(noun) + " " + v.get(verb) + " " + n.get(noun2) + " " +  "and" + " " + v.get(verb2) + " " + n.get(noun3));
```

inside the loop, if you want it to be re-generated numerous times, like so:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 5) {
   int noun = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
   int verb = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
   int noun2 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
   int verb2 = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
   int noun3 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
   String a = new String(n.get(noun) + " " + v.get(verb) + " " + n.get(noun2)   + " " +  "and" + " " + v.get(verb2) + " " + n.get(noun3));
   System.out.println(a);
   x++;
 }
```

Comment: your solution still has the current flaw OP has, because you're not generating a random number each time within the loop.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw, completely skipped that part. Will update, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need regenerate a random string instead of using the one string. Just put the random logic to the while loop. You can try:

```
List<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
    n.add("Allen");
    n.add("beer");
    n.add("Johnson");
    n.add("bar");
    n.add("girl");
    List<String> v = new ArrayList<String>();
    v.add("shot");
    v.add("drank");
    v.add("ate");
    v.add("hit");
    v.add("tossed");

    int x = 0;
    while (x < 5) {
        int noun = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
        int verb = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
        int noun2 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
        int verb2 = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
        int noun3 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
        String a = n.get(noun) + " " + v.get(verb) + " " + n.get(noun2) + " " + "and" + " " + v.get(verb2) + " " + n.get(noun3);

        System.out.println(a);
        x++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "re-randomize" your random variables with each run through the while loop. Even though you use `Math.random()` to declare a variable it won't change every time you use it. Once you declare a variable, it doesn't change unless you change it by giving it a new value. So, you would want to do this:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 5) {
     int noun = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
     int verb = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
     int noun2 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
     int verb2 = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
     int noun3 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
     String a = new String(n.get(noun) + " " + v.get(verb) + " " + n.get(noun2)   + " " +  "and" + " " + v.get(verb2) + " " + n.get(noun3));

     System.out.println(a);
     x++;
}
```

This way, you are changing the values of `noun`, `verb`, and so on, with every iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your "random" variables BEFORE you enter your while loop.  So with every iteration of your while loop, you are using the same values.  In order to have a different result in each iteration, you will need to include the random number generation within your while loop as well.

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 5) {
   int noun = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
   int verb = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
   int noun2 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
   int verb2 = (int)(Math.random() * v.size());
   int noun3 = (int)(Math.random() * n.size());
   String a = new String(n.get(noun) + " " + v.get(verb) + " " + n.get(noun2)   + " " +  "and" + " " + v.get(verb2) + " " + n.get(noun3));

   System.out.println(a);
   x++;
```

}